# How to handle directories with spaces?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I want to use PowerShell with `robocopy` to move a large number of files.  The code below works if there are no spaces in any directory.  How do I improve this to handle directories with spaces?

```
$workingDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath
$sourceDir = "$workingDirectory\source folder"
$targetDir = "$workingDirectory\target folder"
$logFile = "$workingDirectory\log.txt"
$options = "/copyall /b /is /r:5 /w:5 /log:$logFile"
Start-Process robocopy -args "$sourceDir $targetDir $options" -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait
```

Comment: `Start-Proces robocopy ...` -> `& robocopy "$sourceDir" "$targetDir" $options`

Comment: @js2010 The error message comes from `robocopy` and says *'ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "C:\temp\target"'* due to lack of quotes around the path strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see the error when using Start-Process:

```
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "...\target"
```

However, running robocopy directly requires no special quoting.  Note that /copyall requires admin privs.

```
robocopy $sourcedir $targetdir /copyall /b /is /r:5 /w:5 /log:$logFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specific error it's tough to say exactly. You can add escaped quotes around `$sourceDir` and `$targetDir` so that PowerShell doesn't strip the quotes out when starting a new process to execute `robocopy`.

```
Start-Process robocopy -args `"$sourceDir`", `"$targetDir`", $options -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from Ansgar Wiechers, I was able to figure it out.  Thanks :-)

```
$workingDirectory = Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath
$SourceDir = "$workingDirectory\source folder"
$targetDir = "$workingDirectory\target folder"
$logFile = "$workingDirectory\log.txt"
$options = "/copyall /b /is /r:5 /w:5 /log:$logFile"
& robocopy "$sourceDir" "$targetDir" /copyall /b /is /r:5 /w:5 "/log:$logFile"
```